# Are Monero hashes generated based off of the block header?

Tags: mining

Are miners generating POW hashes based off of the block header or is it just guess and check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially. A block hashing blob is constructed which includes the block header, a miner coinbase transaction, a merkle tree root hash of the blocks transaction hashes, and a count of the transactions. This is updated with a nonce and only then hashed and checked.